# Need to add custom javascript to a dialog in sugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I need some help with a custom module for sugarCRM 6.5 CE.  Here is what I want.  On a contact page there is a activity section.  The dropdown has an option "Compose Email".  I have created some files that adds a new option.  I want this option to open the same compose email and then after the email is sent I want to perform some additional functions.  Here is my problem, I have succeeded in adding the new option and making it upgrade safe and adding a after_save hook to do the additional functions.  What I am having trouble with I can't figure out how to tell the difference between the regular compose email and the new compose email option.

I think the easiest way might be to add some new javascript to the email dialog and send an additional parameter to the server indicate something else can be done.  I can't figure out how to have this additional javascript can be incorporated into the compose email dialog.  It looks like the compose email dialog is built differently than other views.  I think I know how to modify some of the core files, but I want to make it upgrade safe so I don't want to touch the core.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I would recommend is extending the class used for email composition.  You will need to add a new entry point (look on the SugarCRM Forum for a step-by-step), to a file in your new directory.  This file should extend the base email class, and the only thing you will need to do is override the default method for saving or sending the email (assuming this is where the additional functions are needing to go).

Once you have the extension, you will just modify the URI to point at this new entry point, and everything else should function the same.

Hope this helps!